# foreign key enforcement not working with sqlalchemy and postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy with postgresql in python to do database operation, below are the files...

```
#connection.py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+psycopg2://user:user123@127.0.0.1/sserp"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autoflush=False, autocommit=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

#models.py
from db.connection import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class Services(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'services'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    point = Column(String, nullable=False)
    service_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('service_types.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'))
    pop_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('pops.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'))
    bandwidth = Column(Integer)
    extra_info = Column(String)
    service_types = relationship('ServiceTypes', back_populates='services')
    pops = relationship('Pops', back_populates='services')

class ServiceTypes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'service_types'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(String)
    services = relationship('Services', back_populates='service_types')

class Pops(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pops'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    owner = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('vendors.id'), nullable=False)
    extra_info = Column(String)
    vendors = relationship('Vendors', back_populates='pops')
    services = relationship('Services', back_populates='pops')

#db_queries.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, joinedload
import db.models as models

def delete_pop(db: Session, pop_id: int) -> int:
    pop_in_db = db.query(models.Pops).filter(models.Pops.id==pop_id).first()
    db.delete(pop_in_db)
    db.commit()
    
    return pop_id`
```

foreign key is enforced in the postgresql database when using postgresql cli,

```
delete from pops;
ERROR:  update or delete on table "pops" violates foreign key constraint       "services_pop_id_fkey" on table "services"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(16) is still referenced from table "services".
```

but foreign key constraint does not work when deleting data using sqlalchemy, data deletes without throwing any error, can't find what is wrong, would greatly appreciate help from experts

Comment: data deleted from pops table without any error

Comment: `ondelete='RESTRICT'` this means you can't delete data that is still in use somewhere. You need cascade.

Comment: @python_user

SQLAlchemy        2.0.23

Comment: @FrankHeikens

where should I put the cascade option?

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is, its the session.delete() function call. in this way sqlalchemy first tries to update the table 'services' column 'pop_id' entry to Null and then delete the 'pops' table entry. I have found two ways to solve this.

1. to apply not null constraint in the 'services' table column 'pop_id', when sqlalchemy tries to update 'pop_id' column to Null, not null constraint triggers and deletion fails

> pop_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('pops.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'), nullable=False)

2. use sqlalchemy.delete instead of sqlalchemy.session.delete, where sqlalchemy tries to delete the entry in the 'pops' table directly and the "ondelete='RESTRICT'" constraint prevents deletion

> ```
> from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
> from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
> from sqlalchemy import delete
>
> def delete_pop(db: Session, pop_id: int) -> any:
>     stmt = delete(models.Pops).where(models.Pops.id==pop_id)
>
>     try:
>        db.execute(stmt)
>     except IntegrityError as e:
>        return f'Integrity error: {e}'
>     
>     return pop_id
> ```